# Array map() retrieve old items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

As I know, `The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.` I am having an array of objects. I want to render each item and it is working properly ! Here's the code I am using ->

```
<div className="itemsSection__items">
      {items &&
        items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Item
              key={Math.random()}
              imageUrl={item.image}
              userName={item.userName}
            />
          );
        })}
    </div>
```

But after the items are rendered, I tried to console the `items`. But it only gives me an empty array (`[]`). So, even after the `map` function, how can I retrieve the items ?

**Edit:**

```
 socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("connected");
  });

  socket.on("newItem", (item) => {
    const newItem = JSON.parse(item);
    console.log(items)
  });
```

Here when I try consoling the items, it is an empty array !

Thanks !

Comment: Where is the code that tries to `console.log()` the item list?

Comment: Sounds like you are doing the logging before the items have been received

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox to reproduce the issue? As nothing seems to be wrong with the code you have shared. Unrelated: Using array `index` as key would be better than `key={Math.random()}`. The best would be to use some stable ID like `item.id` (if you have it).

Comment: Code looks good, can you share the code in codesandox with where you giving console.log ? One suggestion better to use index in key , Math.random() chances for  duplicate element

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: Your console log shows empty because setState is Async method. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/30782948/2873538